# MySQL JOIN doesn't return value

Tags: mysql, select, join, echo

I have mysql query and it seems to work but doesn't return values from payments table.
What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT members.id, members.name, members.lastname 
FROM members 
JOIN (SELECT payments.id, payments.user_id,  payments.begin_date,
MAX(payments.finish_date) AS finish_date, payments.price 
FROM payments 
GROUP BY payments.user_id) 
AS payments 
WHERE members.id=payments.user_id AND payments.finish_date>=CURDATE() 
ORDER BY payments.finish_date ASC, payments.id ASC`
```

and I use:

```
echo stripslashes($wiersz['begin_date']);
```

to return row data.

Comment: If no rows are returned than no records match your criteria. It doesn't mean the query is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you need a JOIN from a Sub-Query?

Comment: Did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to note that you did not select the begin_date field in the main query:

```
SELECT members.id, members.name, members.lastname FROM ...
```

Try using

```
SELECT members.id, members.name, members.lastname, begin_date FROM ...
```

Andrei

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. You may accept the answer in case it helps others, too.

Answer (score 0):

Is the finish_date just a date or does it have hours, minutes and seconds also? You could try this and format the date

```
WHERE members.id=payments.user_id AND DATE(payments.finish_date) >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY DATE(payments.finish_date) ASC, payments.id ASC
```